# pymongo: How to insert a field to an already existing document

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I was wondering how to add a field to an already existing document. I don't have a current code yet, but If I wanted to add a field: {'time': 1}, how would I insert that to a field with the id of 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where `foo` is the collection, Using [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/#Updating-$set) will add a new field if it doesn't exist already:

```
db.foo.find()
db.foo.update({},{$set: {"time":1}},false,true)
```